# Почему когда добавляю к контроллеру HttpPost то страница не открывается?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
@Model.coins

<div id="results"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = $('#input_price').val();
            name = encodeURIComponent(name);            
            $('#results').load('@Url.Action("Test", "Cont1")?name=' + name)

        });
    });
</script>
```

При добавлении HttpPost страница при открытии зависает. Время подключения к базе данных истекает.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string s_)
{}
```

Comment: потому что Вы ее пытаетесь загрузить GET-ом

Comment: потому указываете ему обрабатывать только `post` запросы, и при этом хотите загрузить их через `get` метод `$.load`

Comment: А как обработать post запрос?

Comment: отправить пост запрос..

Comment: или поставить в вашем случае HttpGet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аттрибут [HttpPost] указывает на то, что данный метод контроллера должен получать только post-запросы. Javascript-метод load в вашем случае отправляет GET-запрос. Поэтому он не обрабатывается вашим приложением на сервере.
Используйте [HttpGet] вместо [HttpPost] или отправляйте post-запрос:

```
$('#results').load('@Url.Action("Test", "Cont1")', { name: name })
```

Здесь метод load отправит именно post-запрос, так как параметры запроса указаны в виде объекта.